# Why Apache started directing to different document root after commenting the HTTPS/ SSL?

Tags: apache2, apache-config

I commented out HTTP to HTTPS URL Rewrite in my available site config *cloud.conf* and to my site it is not pointing to `/var/www/html/` when earlier it was pointing to `/var/www/php/`! The only thing present in configuration is below.

*cloud.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName     192.168.1.3
      DocumentRoot   /var/www/php/

      <Directory /var/www/php/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                order allow,deny
                allow from all
      </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

If I try enabling site:

```
$ sudo a2ensite cloud
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
Site cloud already enabled
```

It says it's already enabled.

in the default apache2.conf I have

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory /var/www/php/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Even after `sudo systemctl restart apache2` or `sudo systemctl reload apache2`! I have noticed that redirection of HTTP to HTTPS is still occurring and don't know what is driving that do I have to disable any module?

Comment: and there is no .htaccess in the site root?

Comment: There is no `.htaccess` in the site root. I tried .apachectl -S` it shows DocumentRoot is `/var/www/html/` but I m nowhere setting it, not even in apache2.conf